# Dumping the memory contents of an array

Tags: c, arrays

My main question here relates to the use and formatting specifiers of printf(). I have an array of 100 elements containing integers, most that are currently initialized to zero. I would like to dump the contents to the screen in a 10x10 block formatted like so:

```
       0     1     2     3     4     5 ...
0  +0000 +0000 +0000 +0000 +0000 +0000
1  +0000 +0000 ...
2  ...
3
...
```

With my current code, my formatting is a bit off -

```
    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9    
    +1103   +4309   +1234   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000
0   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000
1   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000
2   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000
3   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000
4   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000
5   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000
6   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000
7   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000
8   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000   +0000
9
```

Current (relevant) code:

```
void dump (int *dumpMemory, int SIZE) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 10; ++i) {                          // Output 1-10 at top row of dump
        printf("\t%d", i);
    }
    puts("");
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("\t%+05d", dumpMemory[i]);

        if ((i % 10) == 9) {
            printf("\n%d", (i / 10));
        }
    }
    puts("");
}
```

The left index has been shifted down a spot, therefore not properly representing its location when printed to the screen.

Comment: You want the newline after the entry where the modulus is 9, not 0.  You might only want the extra newline when the loop does not end with a column 9 entry.  Then you check modulus 0 after the loop.

Comment: Updated above with the output, changing the operation equal to 9. I'm a bit confused as to why it then shifts the index down a spot.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly a question of printing things in the right places.  The heading line is fine.  You need to print the line prefix before you print the entry when `i % 10 == 0`; you need to print the newline after you print the entry when `i % 10 == 9`; after the loop, if `i % 10 != 0`, you need to print a newline to terminate the line of numbers.  It is then optional whether you add another to put a blank line after the dump.

```
void dump(int *data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)  // Output headings 0..9
        printf("\t%d", i);
    putchar('\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (i % 10 == 0)
            printf("%d", i / 10);   // Consider outputting i?
        printf("\t%+05d", data[i]);
        if (i % 10 == 9)
            putchar('\n');
    }
    if (size % 10 != 0)
        putchar('\n');  // Finish current/partial line
    putchar('\n');      // Optional blank line
}
```